# Apply same displacement to other object

Tags: displacement

Sorry for this probably noob question, I'm kinda new to Blender.

I displaced the floor using the clouds texture and I'd like to place the wooden path on top of that, without having gaps. How can I make the path follow the same displacement as the floor?
And as a bonus; Is it also possible to make the grass not go through the path?

Thank you so much in advance for your help :))

Sam
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

add a ground plane and add displace modifier.
[image: ground plane with displacement]

add another plane above the ground plane. do not add thickness now. it may behave unexpectedly with next modifier.
[image: ground and path plane]

add shrinkwrap modifier to the path plane and choose the ground plane as the target object.
[image: shrinkwrap modifier]

add solidify modifier now to give some volume to the path.
[image: solidify modifier]

Comment: You are the best! Thank you so much for your effort!

Comment: @SamvanMeijel mark the question as solved if this helped :)